# ProcessBuilder: process doesn't finish without "redirectOutput"

Tags: java, java-8, process, processbuilder

I'm automating a gradle build using Java. I execute "gradlew.bat" in a Process created from a ProcessBuilder. Here's the code:

```
ProcessBuilder gradlewProcessBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(mainDirPath.concat("\\android\\gradlew.bat"), "assembleDebug");
gradlewProcessBuilder.directory(new File(mainDirPath.concat("/android")));
gradlewProcessBuilder.redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT); //This is the line
Process gradlewProcess = gradlewProcessBuilder.start();
gradlewProcess.waitFor();
```

Now this code works flawlessly, but it outputs the gradle console through the application console and I don't want that. If I delete this line:

```
gradlewProcessBuilder.redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
```

The process hangs in *waitFor()* indefinitely.

I have absolutely no idea how could redirectOutput have effect over this, any light you can shed is welcome.

Comment: If not redirecting the output, how is the output handled? See also [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process. Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for things like paths containing space characters.

Comment: When you don’t redirect the output, you must read it. If you don’t, where’s the problem? Just redirect it. But you can do the whole thing as simple as `new ProcessBuilder(mainDirPath + "\\android\\gradlew.bat", "assembleDebug") .directory(new File(mainDirPath + "/android")) .inheritIO() .start() .waitFor()`

Answer (score 2):

If the output is not redirected or handled, then a default output buffer is allocated. However, on Windows the output buffer is very small; when it fills up, the app will stop executing and will block until the output buffer is drained.

Therefore, you need to drain the output somehow; either by using INHERIT or by having a thread which drains the output. I recommend using https://github.com/zeroturnaround/zt-exec since it has much better default handling.

Comment: Thank you apparently the same problem occurs on MacOS